# Write in CSV first line using Jmeter JSR233 Postprocessor

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

How could I write in the first line of a CSV file using the JSR233 Postprocessor?

Here is my code

```
temp_tax = new FileOutputStream("C://Users/eingel.f/Documents/jmtr/D1_Non_Reseller/temp_tax_rate.csv", true);
file = new PrintStream(temp_tax);

String tax_rate = source[parent]["tax_rate"]
file.println(tax_rate+","+tax_rate+","+tax_rate)

file.close();
temp_tax.close();
```

}`
This piece of code writes this in the [CSV File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqPPj.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code, according to [FileOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) JavaDoc this `true` parameter stands for `append`, i.e. it will add new line(s) to existing file

```
FileOutputStream("C://Users/eingel.f/Documents/jmtr/D1_Non_Reseller/temp_tax_rate.csv", true);
                                                                 ---------------------> ^^^^
```

So it might be the case the file:

- exists already
- has this new line at the beginning

So I think you can use [vars.getIteration()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html#getIteration--) function and if this is the first iteration of your test - set `append` parameter to `false` and vice versa.

More information on this `vars` shorthand and other JMeter API shortcuts available for the JSR223 Test Elements: [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer but the problem still persists I might just look for a way that this problem wont bother my test plan. Thanks!